# How should I match both the Strings which I am getting from Flask API "prediction: " and from manually made Json in angular

Tags: python, angular, flask-restful

My angular Contains this:

```
const purfumes = [{
  id: 1,
  categories: [{
    Catogery: 'Citrus',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Citrus/FR1.jpg', description: 'HEllo'},
      {image: 'assets/images/Citrus/FR-Citrus-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Citrus/FRCITRUS-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Citrus/FRCITRUS-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Citrus/FRCITRUS-5.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Citrus (Zesty or tangy notes like mandarins or limes)']",
  }, {
    Catogery: 'Floral',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-1.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-2.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-3.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-4.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-5.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Floral/FRFLORAL-6.png', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Floral (Smells like fresh-cut flowers - imagine rose, lily or jasmine)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Fruity',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-4.jfif', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-5.png', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Fruity/FRFRUITY-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Fruity (Sweet, edible and tropical like peach, pear and apple)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Green',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-5.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Green/FRGREEN-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Green (Smells of freshly mowed lawns and crushed green leaves)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Oceanic',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-5.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oceanic/FROCEANIC-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Oceanic (Aquatic scents that smell of sea spray or rain mixed with oceanic notes)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Oriental',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-5.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Oriental/FRORIENTAL-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Oriental (Sweet, warm notes like cinnamon, vanilla and musk)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Spicy',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-5.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Spicy/FRSPICY-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Spicy (raw fresh aroma of cardamom, sage or saffron)']",
  },{
    Catogery: 'Woody',
    scents: [
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-1.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-2.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-3.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-4.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-5.jpg', description: ''},
      {image: 'assets/images/Woody/FRWOOD-6.jpg', description: ''},
    ],
    type: "prediction: ['Woody [Chypre] (Aromatic scents like cedar-wood, sandalwood, bergamot or vetiver)']",
  }]
}]
```

And from the flask API Model went I post data into it I get in response:

```
{prediction: "['Woody [Chypre] (Aromatic scents like cedar-wood, sandalwood, bergamot or vetiver)']"}
```

I want to match the following response above with the type param in my categories JSON string

I tried to match in angular using

```
if (this.posteddata === this.recommend.categorys[0].type) {
        this.router.navigate([`/result`]);
      }else {
        alert("string doesnt match");
      }
```

`this.posteddata` is the var which I am gett from flask API python 
but it every time gives me `string doesn't match`

Can anyone please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
Object.entries(this.posteddata).forEach(([key, value]) => {
   console.log(key, value);
});
```

and you will get ***prediction*** in a key and ***['Woody [Chypre] (Aromatic scents like cedar-wood, sandalwood, bergamot or vetiver)']*** in the value.

Now, you can compare `type` with `value`